# Deformation theory and algebraic stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, algebraic-stacks

Let $Vect_{n}(C)$ the moduli stack of vector bundles $V$ of rank $n$ over a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g$. It is well known that $Vect_{n}(C)$  is a smooth stack of  dimension $n^{2}(g-1)=\dim(H^{0}(C,End(V)))-\dim(H^{1}(C,End(V)))$

Intuitively, the first term counts the space of automorphisms and the second the space of deformations. However my question is basically **why is necesary to consider deformations when building moduli stacks**. My guess is that $V$ and its deformation $V_{\varepsilon}$  are going to have different topological data (chern classes for example?).

Otherwise, I don't see why you have to consider them as different points in the moduli stack as the difference between them would be somewhat formal and not real (with formal I refer, for example, to the information of the formal neighbourhood of schemes which is not captured at level of varieties (and should not be captured at the level of this example as it deals with algebraic curves as varieties, not as schemes)).

Comment: Wouldn't the cohomology of $End(V)$ have more to do with deformations of $V$ than of $C$?

Comment: I think that it is the cohomology of the curve $C$ with coefficients in $End(V)$ not the cohomology of $End(V)$

Comment: Sure, this is a standard abuse of terminology. My point is that deformations of $C$ are controlled by the cohomology of its tangent bundle. What I am not getting is why you think $H^i(C,End(V))$ counts something related to $V$ when $i=0$, but something just related to $C$ when $i=1$.

Comment: True, you count the deformation and automorphisms of $V$ in both cases.  So my question is still the same: Why consider these deformations when analyzing the moduli space? Are V and its deformation $V_{\varepsilon}$ going to have the same topological data (chern classes for example)? If so, I don't see why you have to consider them as different points in the moduli stack as the difference between them would be somewhat formal and not real (that formal info is for example the information of the formal neighbourhood of schemes which is not captured at level of varieties)

Comment: Deformation theory is "the local study of moduli problems." The deformation spaces you compute as cohomology groups may not always correspond to honest deformations, but they compute the dimension because they typically constitute the tangent space to the moduli space (obviously all of this has to be made precise in stacky language and all that). But the non-zero deformations correspond to different points because they produce non-isomorphic bundles, although any two general sheaves parametrized by the same moduli space/stack will have the same basic numerical invariants...

Comment: ...But I'm not sure where you got the idea that the notion of formal neighborhood corresponds to things that are not "real." Two bundles being deformations of one another just means that they are "nearby" as points of the moduli space.